# For Loop Duplicating GUI.Button (UNITY3d)

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to display all my servers in the string array 'servers' with this for loop.

```
string[] servers = serverlist.Split(',');

            if(connecting)//Connect Window
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < servers.Length-1; i++)
                {
                    GUI.Box (new Rect(10, i * 30, 130, 50), servers[i], skin.GetStyle("size17 Text"))   
                    if(GUI.Button (new Rect(460, i * 30, 130, 50), "Add", skin.GetStyle("Button 2.0")))
                    {
                        print (i);
                    }
                }
            }
```

If I have 2 servers running, When I open the connect window (connecting) I have the 2 servers as desired.
'Server 1 - Server 2'

However my problem is if I close and reopen the connect window It duplicates those servers so I end up with.
'Server 1 - Server 2 - Server 1 - Server 2'

Any assistance would be very appreciated! Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Silly me....

Add `serverList = "";` whenever I close connecting window.